# Export MS Access query into Excel

Tags: ms-access

In Access, I know that there is a "Analyze it with Microsoft Office Excel" option, but i am creating a database and the person requesting this wants a command button on a form to do the same thing that the "Analyze it with Microsoft Office Excel" button does. So my question is can anyone help me write vba code to export a MS Access query into Excel, formatted the exact way the "Analyze it with Microsoft Office Excel" does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` ... except you said you want the exact same formatting as you get from "*Analyze It with Microsoft Office Excel*"

To duplicate the formatting, you can use:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdOutputToExcel
```

However, that creates a spreadsheet from the active object, and if run from a command button on a form, the form will be the active object ... so you would create a spreadsheet of the form ... which is not what you want.

Since your goal is to create a spreadsheet of a query, add a text box (txtQueryName) for the user to indicate which query to export.

Then your command button click event could be something like this:

```
Private Sub cmdAnalyzeWithExcel_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenQuery Me.txtQueryName
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdOutputToExcel
    DoCmd.Close acQuery, Me.txtQueryName
End Sub
```

That is crude, but it works for me with Access 2003.  I think a better approach would be to load a combo or list box control with the available query names and let the user make her selection from there.  You're on your own for that.

If it were me, I wouldn't try to do this from a command button.  I think a custom menu or ribbon item would be more appropriate.  Or it could be simpler to create an AutoKeys macro which assigns a keyboard shortcut to run a procedure (or call another macro) which does `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdOutputToExcel`  If AutoKeys sounds good to you, see [Run an Access macro by using a keyboard shortcut](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/run-an-access-macro-by-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-HA010239111.aspx)